# omniauth model generation frozen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth-facebook

I am trying to install omniauth with a website running devise. I am following an online tutorial. I ran a command to generate a model, but it just freezes loading. it does not return any errors, or anything. it just displays the command in terminal with no response.

```
rails g model identity user:references provider:string did:string
```

Does anyone have any any idea what is happening, and why?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of spring.

Try stopping it and trying again:

```
bin/spring stop
```